# Pythonic way to calc distance between list of points

Tags: python

I have a list of unorered points (2D) and I want to calculate the sum of distances between them. 
As my background is a c++ dev I would do it like this:

```
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def distance(P1, P2):
    return math.sqrt((P2.x-P1.x)**2 + (P2.y-P1.y)**2)

points = [Point(rand(1), rand(1)) for i in range(10)]

#this part should be in a nicer way
pathLen = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    pathLen += distance(points[i-1], points[i])
```

Is there a more pythonic way to replace the for loop? e.g with reduce or something like that?

best regards!

Comment: All distances between every couple of points? Or is is like a single path between the points?

Comment: **Beware**: you wrote `math.sqrt((P1.x+P2.x)**2 ...`. A distance uses a **`-`** not a **`+`**. It is expected for `distance(P, P)` to be 0!

Comment: thanks, changed that. Didn't focused on the math :D

Comment: The cleanest *and* most efficient way would be to use numpy, which provides methods which allow to write it in a very matlab like syntax and uses optimized routines for calculating a lot of distances at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator expresion with `sum`, `zip` and itertools `islice` to avoid duplicating data:

```
from itertools import islice
paathLen = sum(distance(x, y) for x, y in zip(points, islice(points, 1, None)))
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/GrizzledGrotesqueInstance)

Comment: This seems to be 10% faster than the zip example.

Comment: Nice, I hadn't come across `islice` before, it's clearly what I was actually looking for in my answer rather than my clumsy actual slicing.

Answer (score 1):

A few fixes, as a C++ approach is probably not the best here:

```
import math
# you need this import here, python has no rand in the main namespace
from random import random

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    # there's usually no need to encapsulate variables in Python

def distance(P1, P2):
    # your distance formula was wrong 
    # you were adding positions on each axis instead of subtracting them
    return math.sqrt((P1.x-P2.x)**2 + (P1.y-P2.y)**2)

points = [Point(random(), random()) for i in range(10)]
# use a sum over a list comprehension:
pathLen = sum([distance(points[i-1], points[i]) for i in range(10)])
```

@Robin Zigmond's `zip` approach is also a neat way to achieve it, though it wasn't immediately obvious to me that it could be used here.

Comment: IMHO, it is much clear and simpler to use a single iteration that zipping here. +1

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and pieced together a numpy solution which I think works nicely.

Namely, if you cast your list of points as a numpy array you can then do the following:

```
pts = np.asarray(points)
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((pts[np.newaxis, :, :]-pts[:, np.newaxis, :])**2, axis=2))
```

dist results in a nxn numpy symmetric array where the distance between each point to every other point is given above or below the diagonal.  The diagonal is each point's distance to itself so just 0s.

You can then use:

```
path_leng = np.sum(dist[np.triu_indices(pts.shape[0], 1)].tolist())
```

to collect the top half of the numpy array and sum them to get the pathlength.